# Add translation to an existing refinerycms extension

Tags: refinerycms

Hi I followed the Sunil [tutorial](http://sunil1.com/?q=content/refinery-2-add-translation-pre-generated-refinery-engine) but I'm getting the following db error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11.2ms
pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
Processing by Refinery::PagesController#home as HTML
Parameters: {"locale"=>:es}

SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:
relation "refinery_project_translations" does not exist
2014-12-29T14:14:46.684169+00:00 app[web.1]:
LINE 5:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"refinery_project_translati...
2014-12-29T14:14:46.684177+00:00 app[web.1]:
ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
```

Migration file:

```
class CreateProjectTranslations < ActiveRecord::Migration 
   def up 
      ::Refinery::Projects::Project.create_translation_table!({:description => :string},
      :migrate_data => true) 
      remove_column :refinery_projects, :description 
   end 
   def self.down 
      add_column :refinery_projects, :description, :string 
      ::Refinery::Projects::Project.drop_translation_table! :migrate_data => true 
   end 
end
```

after running the migration the I realize is not not creating the the translation table for projects.

Model:

```
module Refinery
  module Projects
    class Project < Refinery::Core::BaseModel
      self.table_name = 'refinery_projects'

      translates :description

      attr_accessible :name, :description, :date_started, :date_conclusion,
                      :position, :relevance, :img_id, :project_id, :status 

      validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
      has_many :project_images
      has_many_page_images

      class Translation 
           attr_accessible :locale 
      end

    end
  end
end
```

what I'm I missing here?

Comment: @pardt maybe you can point me on the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue moving the migration file from the extension to the app migration folder. After that the application was able to create the table for the translation.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a command to generate the extension. If to use it on an existing one, it`ll add all required code to already existing files by overriding them. Be careful with that - commit files before.

```
rails g refinery:engine Service title:string description:text icon:image --i18n title description
```